# QDoubleSpinBox thousand separator while user is typing

Tags: qt, qspinbox

I want to make a `QDoubleSpinBox` that would format the value into currency so it would be readable by users.

Example.

[image]

So far I've accomplished these things:

- set `showGroupSeparator` to true - but it will only work when focus is released.
- used the `valueChanged` signal to update the group separators directly by calling `ui->doubleSpinBox->setValue(amount);`

  ```
  void DialogCashPayment::on_sbAmount_valueChanged(double arg1)
  {
      ui->sbAmount->setValue(arg1);
  }
  ```

**The Problem** is

> The cursor position will not be in the correct position when the
>   amount is > than 10k, sometimes the amount will completely disappear.
>   in short its really buggy.

Is there any approach on this? Maybe I've overlooked something simple. Please raise a comment if something is not clear. Thanks!

Comment: You can try to change the cursor position manually to the desired position after you changed the value in your slot.

Comment: Hi i also tried that in the docu but the closest i've got was the keyboardTracking but i could not find it. i was searching for something like setCursorPosition but found none.

Comment: You can get the line edit object with [`QDoubleSpinbox::lineEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#lineEdit). Then you can use [`QLineEdit::setCursorPosition`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#cursorPosition-prop).

Comment: Have you solved your problem?